# The sum of infinite series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Determine the sum of the  infinite series
>
> $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}2\sin\left(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k+1}\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{k+1}\right).$$

Comment: Is that an order?

Comment: I simplified. The. equation. and. I get.  2sin[(1/k )-(1/k+1)]cos [(1/k )+(1/k+1)]=sin(2/k)-sin(2/k+1)....now I am stock

Comment: That is much better.  You may also want to learn LaTeX for typing equations.

Comment: No..sorry.. I just. Write the. given question. in my home work

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) or [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This turns out to be a telescoping sum:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left ( \sin{\frac{2}{k}} - \sin{\frac{2}{k+1}}\right ) = \sin{2} - \sin{1} + \sin{1} - \sin{\frac{2}{3}} + \ldots = \sin{2}$$

This sum converges because, as $k \rightarrow \infty$, the summand approaches

$$\frac{2}{k (k+1)} \sim \frac{2}{k^2}$$

so the sum converges by the comparison test.